# Creating a tooltip for displaying error messages when textfield is clicked in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, tooltip

I am creating application wherein I have a registration page. When user enters does not enter any value in a textfield which is mandatory and move on to another textfield a tooltip should be displayed on that textfield showing an error message on it in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `UITexFieldDelegate`
set your `textField.delegate = self;` and then implement the delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
   if(textField.text.length == 0)
   {
     // textField empty
     textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f; // 2 pixels
     textfield.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
     // since there is no text in the texfield we can set its placeholder as tooltip
     textField.placeholder = @"Mandatory field";
   }
}
```

Final result will be a `textField` with 2 pixels red border around it and a placeholder message. This is the easiest approach I can think of. If you wish something more fancy you should create a custom `UIView` and display it when certain `textField` is empty.
Don't forget to include `QuartzCore` framework to your project to enable all `layer` properties.